# How to run Apache without stopping http:sys

Tags: apache, windows-8, port80, http.sys

I know there are a lot of topics about making Apache run, but everything includes stopping the  service that uses port 80, and on Win 7 & 8 this is the `http:sys`, and I don't really want to stop that. I am not sure I won’t have any use for Windows applications that do know about http.sys or whether it will interfere with my .NET development tools, etc, since the port is used by SYSTEM.

I stumbled upon [this article](http://www.mikeplate.com/2011/11/06/stop-http-sys-from-listening-on-port-80-in-windows/) which suggests other solution, meaning to add an extra IP address to the network configuration. BUT there were people complaining of side effects.

So is there any smooth way of making Apache run, but without stopping http.sys. Maybe making it use other port, or best of all - making Apache bind to another port (ex. 8080 or smth like that).